# mysql fails every day at the same time and when many requests occurs

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu-12.04

I am some problems with my mysql database.

I configured a server with the database and other services (apache, php) and put run multiple applications.

There are two problems.

The first: Every day at the same time mysql fails, and I must go and restart it.

The second: Every time I reload the website many times continuously mysql falls, and again and need to restart it.

```
140106  8:30:14 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use$
140106  8:30:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140106  8:30:14 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140106  8:30:14 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140106  8:30:14 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140106  8:30:14 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140106  8:30:14 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140106  8:30:14 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140106  8:30:14 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140106  8:30:14 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140106  8:30:14 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140106  8:30:14 [ERROR] Aborting
140106  8:30:14 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

What's wrong with my database?

Comment: Did you check your error_logs? Judging from your description it could be anything, from too many open files to max connections reached, please refine your description for us to be able to help you

Comment: The applications may not be closing the connections, or it may be open cursor exceeding issue. Check the mysql error_logs

Comment: @jeredepp here are the logs

Comment: @perondi What are your Serverspecs?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem of thinning of the mysql database. The server is running out of memory, I used to solve SWAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like mysql faults because of RAM shortage. May be some app started by cron consume all the memory? That can explain why faults becomes at the same time and why mysql can be started for some period.

Comment: according to his description in which mysql fails at the same time, i agree on checking the crons, this is clearly a memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a memory issue. Either add more RAM, or lower the innodb buffer pool size.

Something like this in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64M
```

Comment: I put this line in my.cnf and when I do multiple requests to mysql it returns to off.